# Improve speed for substring when separating text by number of characters

Tags: r

My data looks like that:

```r
library(data.table)

fake_data <- c(
  "A002JOHN 22M",
  "A003JAMES25M",
  "B234LEE  28M"
)
```

It's a text file where I have to separate the text in columns according to the number of characters. For example, the first 4 characters are one column, the next 5 characters are another column, etc.

Expected output:

```r
    V1    V2 V3 V4
1 A002 JOHN  22  M
2 A003 JAMES 25  M
3 B234 LEE   28  M
```

The method I use for now is the following:

```r
method_1 <- function() {
  tmp <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(fake_data)) {
    tmp[[i]] <- substring(fake_data[i], c(1, 5, 10, 12), c(4, 9, 11, 12))
  }
  
  do.call(rbind, tmp) %>% 
    as.data.frame()
}
```

I thought I could replace `do.call` and `as.data.frame` with the following:

```r
method_2 <- function() {
  tmp <- list()
  for (i in seq_along(fake_data)) {
    tmp[[i]] <- substring(fake_data[i], c(1, 5, 10, 12), c(4, 9, 11, 12))
  }
  
  setDT(transpose(tmp))
}
```

But it makes it slower:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  method_1(),
  method_2(),
  times = 1000
)

> Unit: microseconds
       expr  min    lq     mean median     uq    max neval
 method_1() 50.4  61.4  83.8550   68.8  75.55 4348.9  1000
 method_2() 94.2 108.9 141.1236  115.6 127.30 1211.8  1000
```

Any idea of how I could improve the speed for this operation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think my solution is faster than yours in the post, but this might be another option maybe you would be interested

```
read.table(
  text = gsub(
    "(\\D\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)(.*)",
    "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", 
    fake_data
  )
)
```

which gives

```
    V1    V2 V3 V4
1 A002  JOHN 22  M
2 A003 JAMES 25  M
3 B234   LEE 28  M
```

---

**Explanation**
In `gsub`, we use `()` to group the patterns we want to put into the data frame by columns.

- `(\\D\\d+)`: non-digit character followed by digits
- `(\\D+)`: non-digit characters in a row
- `(\\d+)`: digit characters in a row
- `(.*)`: anything left

Comment: Thanks, could you add a small explanation for the regex?

Comment: @bretauv yes, please see my update

Comment: Also, it is around 7x slower than method 1 in my post (at least on my side), is it the same for you?

Comment: @bretauv yes, I think yours is fast enought.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::separate`:

```r
library(tidyr)

fake_data <- data.frame(
  V1=c("A002JOHN 22M",
  "A003JAMES25M",
  "B234LEE  28M"
))

fake_data |> 
  separate(V1, into=c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), sep=c(4,9,11))
#>     V1    V2 V3 V4
#> 1 A002 JOHN  22  M
#> 2 A003 JAMES 25  M
#> 3 B234 LEE   28  M
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If your fields do not have fixed width, you can use regular expression within `sep=`.

Comment: Apparently this is much slower than methods 1 and 2 in my post (more than 10x slower than method 1 on my side)